# How can I save order place data in custom table along with Magento default tables at the time when customer placed order?

Tags: magento

I want to save all data(customer,product,billing address etc) when customer placed an order in magento into another database flat table. Please help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you tries so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you need to create a module. Here it is:

`app/etc/modules/Tech_Order.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tech_Order>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Tech_Order>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create module configuration file `app/code/community/Tech/Order/etc/config.xml`. As follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Tech_Order>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Tech_Order>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
             <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                   <order_capture>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Tech_Order_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>captureOrder</method>
                   </order_capture>
                </observers>
             </sales_order_place_after>          
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Create Observer file that capture order `app/code/community/Tech/Order/Model/Observer.php`

```
class Tech_Order_Model_Observer {

    public function captureOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $_order     = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $orderObj   = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($_order->getId());

        $orderId    = $_order->getRealOrderId();
        $items      = $orderObj->getAllItems(); 

        $billingAddress = $_order->getBillingAddress();
        $shipingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress();

        foreach($items as $item) {
            $sku = $item->getData('sku');
            $qty        = (int) $item->getQtyOrdered();
            $price      = $item->getprice();
        }

        Mage::log('Order Data -- ' . $orderObj->getData());     
        Mage::log('Billing Address -- '. $billingAddress->getData());       
        Mage::log('Shipping Address -- '. $shipingAddress->getData());      

    }
}
```

`captureOrder` is the fucntion where you can capture all the information of order and save in database.

Comment: Thanks Pankaj, but how we save that data into another database(not magen to) table?

Comment: you can use core mysql function to save data in another database OR you can use zend functions as well